# What type of SAML Test Connector to create for SP-initiated SSO, with the assertion containing attributes?

Tags: onelogin

I don't have admin access to the top-level of my company's OneLogin system.  However, if I tell our IT people to create a particular type of "SAML Test Connector", they will do it and will give me admin access for just that application.  Then I can set it up as I wish.

What I am after is SP-initiated SSO, with the resulting assertion containing the authenticated user's email address as its subject, and with the assertion containing some additional attributes about the user.

The list of [SAML Test Connectors](https://support.onelogin.com/hc/en-us/articles/202673944-How-to-Use-the-OneLogin-SAML-Test-Connector) is somewhat confusing, and I have some questions about it.

Q1) "Test" connector?  Are these connectors only for tests?  Or should I read "test connector" as "custom connector"?

Q2) When a connector is indicated as being "(IdP)" or "(SP)", do this mean "IdP-initiated SSO" and "SP-initiated SSO"?  I'm guessing that it does, but it would be nice not to have to guess.

Q3) The one connector that I actually want, that you would probably describe as "SAML Test Connector (SP w/attr)" isn't actually present!  Does OneLogin support it?

Q4) For attaining SP-initiated SSO with the assertion containing attributes (i.e. what I actually want), what app type do I tell our IT guys to create?

I'm guessing (but again it would be nice not to) that if they created "SAML Test Connector (SP)" then I could tinker with that, and add attributes via the app's configuration.  Correct?

(BTW: I don't need the assertion to be encrypted, and I don't need the response element rather than the assertion element to be signed.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1) Read as "custom connector"

Q2) Yes, when it includes SP you will see that in the "Configuration" tab there is a SP Login URL. That URL will be used to redirect the user there when clicking on the app icon of the dashboard. (It will start a SP-initiaited flow at the IdP, instead of drectly send a SAMLResponse).

Q3) The "SAML Test Connector (SP)" includes attrs

Q4) "SAML Test Connector (SP)"

Answer (score 1):

I have always only used "OneLogin SAML Test (IdP w/ multi value attr)". You can configure it to your needs.

[image]

Comment: Can you create "OneLogin SAML Test (IdP w/ multi value attr)" and then configure it to do SP-initiated SSO instead of IdP-initiated SSO?  I don't have access to our OL system, so I'm flying blind here.  Also, I need to be as sure as possible about this up-front, before I ask them to create an app within our OL system.

Comment: Yes you should. I have never implemented it because during setup we ask the customers to provide us a link to their intranet. This works close enough to the SP initiated SSO and when presented with this option everyone so far has been OK with it.